# Заголовок в GET запросе

Tags: c

пишу программу на сокетах в СИ, которая отправляет Get запрос на сервер и получает в ответ погоду в городе. Для сервиса Яндекс Погода необходимо отправить APIKEY в заголовке. Как описывается заголовок в запросе? Как должен выглядеть запрос?

```
GET https://api.weather.yandex.ru/v2/informers?lat=55.75396&lon=37.620393\r\nX-Yandex-API-Key:[ключ]
```

Пытаюсь отправить вот так, но понимаю, что это не то

Comment: "Вот так" это как? Приведите код в вопросе

Answer (score 1):

Как всегда и бывает нашел ответ после того, как задал вопрос.
Составил запрос следующим образом:

```
GET http://api.weather.yandex.ru/v2/forecast?lat=55.75396&lon=37.620393&extra=true  HTTP/1.0\r\nX-Yandex-API-Key: d....26
```

Забыл ключевое слово `HTTP/1.0` в первой строчке запроса